# KeyJustDown implementation in emscripten using GLFW3

Tags: glfw, emscripten

I want to implement `KeyJustDown` function which checks, if given key was just pressed down. Key was just pressed down, if it is down in the current state and was up in the previous state.

```c
int isKeyJustDown(int key) {
    return !inputState.keysPrev[key] && inputState.keysCurr[key];
}
```

At the beginning of the frame I also update the input state like so:

```c
struct InputState {
    char keysPrev[256];
    char keysCurr[256];
} inputState;

void updateInput() {
    memcpy(inputState.keysPrev, inputState.keysCurr, 256);

    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

This works fine with glfw3 application on desktop. Callbacks are dispatched when `glfwPollEvents` function is called. However this does not apply when using emscripten.

**I have two questions.** When exactly are callbacks dispatched when using emscripten (do they happen as soon as event occurs or is there a certain point in the loop it happens)? And how can I achieve the same behaviour as on desktop when using emscripten?

Here is the full example:

```c
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
#include <emscripten.h>
#endif

GLFWwindow *window;

struct InputState {
    char keysPrev[256];
    char keysCurr[256];
} inputState;

void updateInput() {
    memcpy(inputState.keysPrev, inputState.keysCurr, 256);

    glfwPollEvents();
}

int isKeyJustDown(int key) {
    return !inputState.keysPrev[key] && inputState.keysCurr[key];
}

void update() {
    updateInput();

    if (isKeyJustDown(GLFW_KEY_E)) {
        printf("Key E\n");
    }

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}

void keyCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (key < 0) return;

    inputState.keysCurr[key] = action != GLFW_RELEASE;
}

int main() {
    if (!glfwInit()) return 1;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "Input test", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) return 1;
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);

#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
    emscripten_set_main_loop(update, 0, 1);
#else
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        update();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `glfwPollInput` does nothing in the emscripten implementation. The actual event callbacks can happen at any time. To solve my problem I moved `updateInput` function after checking for input:

```c
void update() {
    if (isKeyJustDown(GLFW_KEY_E)) {
        printf("Key E\n");
    }

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    updateInput();
}
```

Relevant links:

https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/pull/2380

https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/issues/2379